# Unable to use variable in curl command

Tags: bash, shell, curl, ksh

I'm trying to use two variables in a curl command on my ksh program, but it doesn't work.

Example:

1. Original URL

   ```
   curl -s --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json" -X POST --data-binary '{"username":"foo","password":"foo_pwd"}' URL site
   ```
2. On my program

   ```
   user=foo
   pwd=foo_pwd
   curl -s --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json" -X POST --data-binary '{"username":"'"$user"'","password":"'"$pwd"'"}' URL site
   ```

I've tried also to escape double quote with backslash but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First examine your script

```
user=foo
pwd=foo_pwd
echo '{"username":"'"$user"'","password":"'"$pwd"'"}'
```

Then run

```
user=foo
pwd=foo_pwd
curl -s --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json" -X POST https://example.com --data-binary '{"username":"'"$user"'","password":"'"$pwd"'"}'
```